# Is there a shortcut to sum the contents of a list in ansible?

Tags: list, ansible, sum, jinja2

I have a list `sList` as:

```
sList = ['12','8','10']
```

I need the sum of all the elements of `sList`.
I came across `sum()` function in jinja2 but it takes attributes etc, and not sure how to use it with a `list`.
I tried:

```
- set_fact:
    sList:
      - '12'
      - '8'
      - '10'

- set_fact:
    sumList: "{{ sum(sList) }}" 

- debug: var=sumList
```

Expected result: sumList = 30, but gets below error:

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'sum' is undefined
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter [sum](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#sum) *"Returns the sum of a sequence of numbers"*. The variable *sList* is a list of strings. The task below will fail

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        sList: ['12', '8', '10']
    - set_fact:
        sumList: "{{ sList|sum }}"
```

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
> msg: 'Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ sList|sum }}): unsupported operand type(s) for +: ''int'' and ''AnsibleUnicode'''

To solve the problem, use a list of numbers. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        sList: [12, 8, 10]
    - set_fact:
        sumList: "{{ sList|sum }}"
    - debug:
        var: sumList
```

give

```yaml
  sumList: '30'
```

The next option is to convert the items of the list to numbers. Map either [int](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#int) or [float](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#float) function. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        sList: ['12', '8', '10']

    - set_fact:
        sumList: "{{ sList|map('int')|sum }}"
    - debug:
        var: sumList

    - set_fact:
        sumList: "{{ sList|map('float')|sum }}"
    - debug:
        var: sumList
```

give

```yaml
  sumList: '30'

  sumList: '30.0'
```

Comment: Great! The list contains string in my case, so used map and int and it worked like a charm!!.
I tried the jinja way but stuck with the ```scoping``` problem.
Thank you Botka!